# Spring Boot dont read data.sql but it read import.sql

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want import DML script after spring creates tables.
I was fighting with **`data.sql`** file but my application **don't see it**.
I don't know why. It works when I rename `data.sql` to **`import.sql`**, but **it should also work** with `data.sql`.

Anybody know why?

My application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yyy
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

I put `data.sql` into `src/main/resources`

When only data.sql is in `resources`:

```
2018-03-21 00:42:13.646  INFO 4740 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@eebc0db'
```

When only import.sql (also in `src/main/resources`):

```
2018-03-21 00:48:57.023  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'ScriptSourceInputFromUrl(file:/C:/Users/Pawel/Desktop/Project/target/classes/import.sql)'
```

When i type `spring.datasource.data=data.sql` into `application.properties`

```
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2" org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueException: Property spring.datasource.data with value 'ServletContext resource [/data.sql]' is invalid: The specified resource does not exist.
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.getResources(DataSourceInitializer.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.getScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.lambda$multicastEvent$0(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can see both `data.sql` and `import.sql` in `target/classes/data.sql`, `target/classes/import.sql` ...

Answer (score 2):

If you put data.sql inside jar then prepend its name with classpath or META-INF

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data.sql

spring.datasource.data=/META-INF/data.sql
```

(I'm not 100% sure so it would be great if you try both solution and give me feedback)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer :)
First of all, I read in docs that it should works without spring.datasource.data, but...
With first option i got `'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@eebc0db'`.
With the second i got: `'ServletContext resource [/META-INF/data.sql]' is invalid: The specified resource does not exist.`

Answer (score 2):

you have to inactivate the Hibernate loading (from import.sql) by commenting your line  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop and setting it to validate.
Then add spring.datasource.initialization:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody have this trouble, here is what I did:

applications.properties :

## Oracle settings

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe<br>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver<br>
spring.datasource.username=xxxx<br>
spring.datasource.password=xxxx<br>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none<br>
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always<br>
spring.datasource.platform=oracle<br>
```

## MYSQL settings

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql<br>
spring.datasource.username = xxxx<br>
spring.datasource.password = xxxx<br>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none<br>
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always<br>
spring.datasource.platform=mysql<br>
```

The lines that helped me was adding the last 2, and also remember that you must have a file with the name "data-oracle.sql" or "data-mysql.sql" respectively.

Here is the source: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

work for me when first option of naXa:

spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data.sql